# How to make a marquee animation which never leave the view blank ? With images

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, animation

I am trying to make a marquee animation, but i can't manage to make it perfect.
As you can see when a logo goes out of the page it do not get back from the otherside directly.

I would like that when a logo get out from left it has to get back from right instantly.

[image]

```
.logos {
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    justify-content: space-evenly;

    img {
        height: 25px;
        margin: 0 20px;
        animation: defile 3s infinite linear;
        position: relative;
    }
}
@keyframes defile {
        25% {left: 0%;}
        50% {left: 100%;}
        75% {right: 100%;}
        100% {right: 0%;}
}

<div className="logos pt-5" >
    <img src="static/img/logos/NEXTJS.png" />
    <img src="static/img/logos/SOCKET.IO.png" />
    <img src="static/img/logos/NODEJS.png" />
    <img src="static/img/logos/JS.png" />
    <img src="static/img/logos/GIT.png" />
    <img src="static/img/logos/NANTES-TECH.png" />
    <img src="static/img/logos/FRENCHTECH.png" />
    <img src="static/img/logos/ANGULAR.png" />
    <img src="static/img/logos/S.png" />
    <img src="static/img/logos/DOCKER.png" />
    <img src="static/img/logos/REACT.png" />
    <img src="static/img/logos/REACT-ROUTER.png" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that project https://github.com/mxmzb/react-marquee-slider.
Which allow me to do what I exactly wanted

Here is the result https://cargouet.com/

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried doing something like:

```css
@keyframes defile {
    0% { left: 0% }
    50% { left: 100% }
    51% { right: 100%; }
    100% { right: 0%; }
}
```

The main issue with what you have for me right now is that it takes 25% of the animation to change from `left: 100%` to `right: 100%;` I think this might be what's not working for you.

**UPDATE**

I checked for some other option and maybe [this script](https://advancetechtutorial.blogspot.com/2015/10/continus-marquee.html) could do the trick for you.

Comment: Thx for you're help, but it didn't really change something. It's like what I did with different  timing.

Comment: @crg I added some extra info that might be of help.